# parse datetime from string provides different results with invariant culture in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, date-parsing

Having the following code:

```
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact("3012", "yyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Why on my machine it prints

> 12/1/2030 12:00:00 AM

and on other machine it prints

> 12/1/1930 12:00:00 AM

Isn't enough to specify the culture for the conversion to be idempotent?

Comment: which runtime ? are the runtime the same in both cases ?

Comment: That's not the issue here. The culture info gives you the format and the format is the same. For some reason, the other machine has an issue with the Y2K or the UNIX Y2K where it parses the time with a long rather than with a ulong. It is an specific OS version issue with the other machine,

Comment: In the settings for date there is an option to specify how the 2 digits year should be considered as part of the 20th century or the 21th century. Obviously the two machines have different settings

Comment: @Steve and can I override that setting? Where can I find this setting?

Comment: Where to find that setting: It is complicated to say the least. Win10 => Search for Control Panel, then choose Geographical Area, click on More Settings Choose Date page and here you should find the year used to split between 1900/2000 - Sorry for imprecisions but translating from different language

Comment: @Steve - I can't find that setting in my Windows. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @Enigmativity Win10 https://imgur.com/a/7pbkrqh Sorry Italian OS

Comment: @Steve - Got it - in English it's under "Region".